# Rails Controller errors: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an app in Rails 4 and trying to run the server. I am getting an error involving the Application controller on line 1. Localhost will not run the server because of this error: **syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input**. The rack session states: **ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x1072f1ef0 not yet loaded**. Here is my Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

There is one more identical application frame error for another controller. Just like the Application controller, it has very little code in it and has the correct amount of 'ends'. In my "All Frames" tab, there is a slew of errors involving ActiveSupport, ActionController, and many others. There's too many to list.

Does anybody have an idea of what is causing these errors? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have all required gems installed? `bundle` should install everything for you.

Comment: Yes, `bundle install` and `bundle update`. Even removed the Gemfile.lock and ran those two commands as well as `bundle`.

Comment: Could you please share the complete stacktrace.

Comment: If multiple controllers lead to the same errors, the controllers probably invoke the same code, which is included from another file. So look for the similarities in both controllers, what external code do they share. If you locate that, you know in which class a end statement is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backtracked through the errors & the application only to find out that the error was being raised through a `require_user` action that had a route that didn't exist.

```
  def require_user!
    redirect_to welcome_path unless signed_in?
  end
```

I don't know why it the server didn't just tell me the error up front, but I fixed it by changing the incorrect route to a route that existed. I appreciate the people who tried to help me with this. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Rails errors and stacktraces can often be quite cryptic. It takes time and experience and a lot of trial and error to really understand what they are telling you.

Answer (score 0):

What if you flip those lines in the `ApplicationController` to look like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper

  protect_from_forgery
end
```

I've never seen anything before the `protect_from_forgery` - just a hunch.

Comment: Nope, just tried flipping them, it didn't change anything. I restarted the server too. It says that the error is on line 1 of the Application controller though, which is really odd.

Comment: There's likely a configuration issue going on then... Something maybe not closed under your `config/` directory...  Have you changed anything in there?

Comment: Under `config/` I've installed the gems Devise and Mailboxer, but I don't think that would do it?

Comment: It's *possible* if you've edited those configs that you're missing a closing `end`.

Comment: In the `config/environments/development.rb` I put this in there: `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
`, but I doubt that would do it?

Comment: I thought it might be this for Devise in the development.rb `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
`, but it wasn't.